# Windows Phone Emulator not running on Windows 8.1 on VirtualBox on Mac Book Pro

Tags: virtualbox, hyper-v, windows-phone-emulator

[[image: 1]][image: I am working on Windows Phone App, recently my system got upgraded to MAC, I installed Oracle Virtual Box and installed Windows 8.1, Using Visual Studio 2015]

[image: Selected Hyper-V under machine settings]

My configuration is:

Mac Book Pro running Virtual Box running Windows 8.1,
There I am getting error.

I have checked in Control Panel>>Programs and Features >> Hyper-V: all the components are checked.
Also, I have checked the services (run>> services.msc) all hyper-V services are running perfectly.

Tried with Windows 10 and Windows 8.1, but no luck.
Any Help will be appreciated !

According to the suggestion given, I uninstalled Hyper-V and tried it again, I got this error "Hyper-V is not enabled"

Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Windows HyperV and Virtual Box are trying to do the same job and will conflict with each other. Since HyperV takes control on boot, you'll need to uninstall HyperV to use the emulator in Virtual Box.

Comment: I uninstalled the Hyper-V, and restarted the computer, then restarted the emulator, now I am getting the error even before, as the build starts it says "Hyper-V is not enabled" see the screenshot above.

Comment: For me, the uninstal of HyperV was all I needed to do - I dont recal having to do anything else.   Checkout this thread https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=75362 - There may be something useful tips in there for you.